# Is there any record of installed plugins in the database?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin

I have my live install on one server and a development install on another. I've added a plugin to both but it only appears in the plugin list in `wp-admin` on one.

For a plugin to appear in `wp-admin` does it need to appear in the database at all? Or is it that just by having the plugin file(s) in the `plugins` directory that it'll be detected?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin file had Mac line endings so the meta-data comment at the top of the file wasn't being parsed properly. e.g.

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: WP JSON-RPC
  Plugin URI: http://plugins.voceconnect.com
  Description: This plugin provides a JSON version of the XML-RPC WordPress API...
  Author: Jeff Stieler
  Version: 0.9.1
*/
```

Answer (score 15):

It saves the data in:

- **wp_options**
- - Row: option_name
- - - active_plugins

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but that's my fault. Take a look at my answer for my findings.

Comment: FYI: You can also save a list of all plugins and their status (active/inactive) and version as txt, csv, json by help of the [Wordpress command line utility](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/) with `wp plugin list --format=csv`. Like you can do with typical package managers such as `apt`, `brew` or `npm`. By help of that list you later re-install all plugins in an automated fashion with `wp plugin install`.

Answer (score 2):

In 99% of cases a plugin isn't detected when moving because the owner of the directory is different from the current owner, meaning no reading rights.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions